# I'm attempting to extract some links from craigslist using beautifulsoup but it's pulling the links 100 times rather than once

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm attempting to extract the links of the most recent tv listings from craigslist. I've gotten it to the point where I get the information that I want but, for some reason it's pulling that information like 100 times before it moves on to the next link. I'm not sure why it's doing that?

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
import csv
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
# id url
url = ('http://omaha.craigslist.org/sya/')
# this opens the url
ourUrl = opener.open(url).read()
# now we are passing the url to beautiful soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(ourUrl)

for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': re.compile("hdrlnk")}):
    find = re.compile('/sys/(.*?)"')
    #time.sleep(1)
    timeset = time.strftime("%m-%d %H:%M") # current date and time
    for linka in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/sys/")}):
        find = re.compile('/sys/(.*?)"')
        searchTv = re.search(find, str(link))
        Tv = searchTv.group(1)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
        url = ('http://omaha.craigslist.org/sys/' + Tv)
        ourUrl = opener.open(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(ourUrl)
        print "http://omaha.craigslist.org/sys/" + Tv
        try:
            outfile = open('C:/Python27/Folder/Folder/Folder/craigstvs.txt', 'a')
            outfile.write(timeset + "; " + link.text + "; " + "http://omaha.craigslist.org/sys/" + Tv + '\n')
            timeset = time.strftime("%m-%d %H:%M") # current date and time
        except:
            print "No go--->" + str(link.text)
```

Here is an example of what it outputs:   08-10 15:19; MAC mini intel core wifi dvdrw great cond ; http://omaha.craigslist.org/sys/4612480593.html 
Which is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish except it extracts that that info about 100+ times. And then moves on the next listing... I'm at a stand still and can't figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks ahead of time!

Scrapy for @alexce:

```
import scrapy
import csv
from tutorial.items import DmozItem
import re
import urllib2
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
import html2text

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["http://omaha.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://omaha.craigslist.org/sya/",

    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//html'):
            #title = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            link = sel.xpath('/html/body/article/section/div/div[2]/p/span/span[2]/a').extract()[0:4]
            #at this point it doesn't repeat itself, which is good!
            #desc = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
    print link
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop here. Other notes/improvements:

- `opener.open()` result can be [passed directly](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup) to `BeautifulSoup` constructor, no need for `read()`
- `urlopener` can be defined once and reused in the loop to follow links
- use [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) instead of `findAll()`
- use [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) for concatenating url parts
- use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for writing the delimited data
- use [`with` context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) while dealing with files

The complete fixed version:

```
import csv
import re
import time
import urllib2
from urlparse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE_URL = 'http://omaha.craigslist.org/sys/'
URL = 'http://omaha.craigslist.org/sya/'
FILENAME = 'C:/Python27/Folder/Folder/Folder/craigstvs.txt'

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
soup = BeautifulSoup(opener.open(URL))

with open(FILENAME, 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    for link in soup.find_all('a', class_=re.compile("hdrlnk")):
        timeset = time.strftime("%m-%d %H:%M")

        item_url = urljoin(BASE_URL, link['href'])
        item_soup = BeautifulSoup(opener.open(item_url))

        # do smth with the item_soup? or why did you need to follow this link?

        writer.writerow([timeset, link.text, item_url])
```

And here is what the code produces:

```
08-10 16:56;Dell Inspiron-15 Laptop;http://omaha.craigslist.org/sys/4612666460.html
08-10 16:56;computer????;http://omaha.craigslist.org/sys/4612637389.html
08-10 16:56;macbook 13 inch 160 gig wifi dvdrw ;http://omaha.craigslist.org/sys/4612480237.html
08-10 16:56;MAC mini intel core wifi dvdrw great cond ;http://omaha.craigslist.org/sys/4612480593.html
...
```

---

Just a side note, since you need to follow the links, get the data and output it into a `csv` file..it is just sounds like [`Scrapy`](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) would be a very good fit here. There are [`Rules`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules), [`Link Extractors`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#topics-link-extractors) and it can [serialize crawled items](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html) into `csv` out of the box.

Comment: thanks that worked, I'm still new to python and was trying to use scrapy  for the same thing but could only get it to extract the link info rather than the text between the ><.

Comment: @SamK yeah, give it another try, once you get how it works and what features it has - you'll have a lot of fun web scraping. It is really powerful and helps to avoid a lot of boilerplate code and saves you time.

Comment: alright you convinced me to give it another shot. The thing was  that I could figure out how to get information beyond the xpath. For example: (/html/body/article/section/div/div[2]/p/span/span[2]/a) I couldn't grab the text associated with the a tag.

Comment: @SamK please elaborate it into a separate question and show the current code of your spider. Throw me the link to the question here. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the code, I didn't post it in a question. I'll add it to my current code up there.

Comment: @SamK I meant create a separate SO question tagged with `Scrapy`. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59070/discussion-between-samk-and-alecxe).